# Software Updates in devices

Tags: updates

I want to know what is actually happening when we upgrade a device's software. For example we upgrade a device from Android ICS to Jellybean. We do download JellyBean from the server. Then we will install it. My question is: during installation does it replaces the ICS in memory or it resides in separate memory?

I know the Kernel is same for both ICS and JB. Can we downgrade to ICS from JB?

Comment: We do have some previous questions on updates, that do answer some parts of your question. For how do updates get to your device, see [Who are responsible for pushing out the OTA updates?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25603/) and [How exactly does operating system update work on Android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36226/). This question has more info on the actual update process [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/). But I don't think we have anything yet on how the actual files are replaced, etc

Comment: Also related are [Why aren't the manufacturers updating the phone to the latest Android version when it's available?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/290/) and [Revert Android Update 4.0 to 3.0/3.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45166/)

Comment: And as a short answer to your first direct question: an update replaces the previously installed version. So before you ask: a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset) only resets the device to factory *settings* (it deletes all user data and user-installed apps), and does *not* revert to the Android version originally installed.

Answer (score 2):

The new version replaces the old version, just like upgrading to a new Windows version or a new version of Ubuntu on your PC.

Also, it's **not** the case that the kernel is the same for ICS and JB. ICS uses a Linux kernel based on the 3.0.1 release, whereas JB's kernel is based on 3.0.31. Android-specific patches to the kernel were also added between the two versions, to support new driver features. But you can downgrade a device to an older version if you have a ROM image to downgrade to, whatever kernel versions they use. The only difference the kernel version makes is that if a device wasn't designed to support a particular kernel version, the manufacturer would have to supply device drivers for the target kernel in order to make a suitable ROM.